# how to add whole json as object with jolt

Tags: json, jolt

this is my input json

```json
{
 "Name": "Back-test job",
 "market": "2",
 "TimeZone": "257",
 "company": "1"
}
```

and I want to add the whole json as an object like this:

```json
{
 "Name": "Back-test job",
 "market": "2",
 "TimeZone": "257",
 "company": "1",

 "wholeJson":{
   "Name": "Back-test job",
   "market": "2",
   "TimeZone": "257",
   "company": "1"}
}
```

do you have any idea for spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the base *json* value twice through use of `&1`, which refers one-level up as having a nested structure `"*": {...}` within the specification of **shift** operation, in one of them prepend with the key `wholeJson` and also apply a **sort** specification against getting unordered result such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&1",
        "@(1,&)": "wholeJson.&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks @Barbaros Özhan but the result is wrong. for example in the new json `"Name" : "Name"`  instead `"Name" : "Back-test job"`

Comment: I changed the $ to @ and it's work..thanks you so much

Comment: right @Meis exactly, I realised that didn't notice that part within the result. Fixed just now, you're welcome.